# How to get the parent node from current node in json?

Tags: json, xml, groovy

In `xmlslurper()`,There is a way to get the parent node from current node using `parent()`. **Example :**

```
def text = '''
    <list>
        <technology>
            <name>Groovy</name>
        </technology>
    </list>
'''

def list = new XmlSlurper().parseText(text)
println list.technology.name.parent().name()
```

**Output**: `technology` 
Is there any method to get to the parent node in **json** file, like shown above  while using `jsonslurper ()` wiht groovy.

**Update 1:**

```
 {"menu": {
    "items": [
        {
            "name":"coke",
            "qty": 2,
            "category":0,
            "sizes":["small","large"]
        },
        {
            "name":"pizza",
            "qty": 1,
            "category":1,
            "sizes":["medium"]
        }
    ],
}}
```

In this json file My current code variable has,

```
def json = new JsonSlurper().parse(new File (filename))
def var= json.menu.items.sizes  // I can't change this
```

Here I want to print output as,

```
coke,2,0,small
coke,2,0,large
pizza,1,1,medium
```

Comment: @tim_yates Here I m updated my requirement. for this purpose that `parent` facility needed.

Comment: You can just go down to `items` and then iterate the sizes to get this output.  The result of JsonSlurper are basically just maps and so don't know where they are in a greater hierarchy.